# node 7.10 - does it support await?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I am on node 7.10:

```
$ node --version
v7.10.0
```

I thought it supports `await`.

```
 let result = await Weather.findOne(options, function(err, weather) {

    if (err) {
        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return res.status(200).send('Error occurs: ' + err);
    }

    if (weather) {
        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return res.status(200).send(key + ' already exist.');
    }

    return weather;
});

console.log(result);
```

Error message:

```
let result = await Weather.findOne(options, function(err, weather) {
                       ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:53:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:95:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/projects/citizen-sense-dustbox-data-streams/es5/v4/app.js:33:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/projects/citizen-sense-dustbox-data-streams/es5/v4/bin/www:7:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:427:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:151:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:542:3
```

It does not seem supported in node 7.10? Or am I doing something wrong?

Any ideas?

Comment: It is supported according to [node.green](http://node.green/#ES2017-features-async-functions-await)

Comment: `async/await` is **not** part of ES7 (ES2016)! It  part of this year's release, ES2018.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await:

> The await operator is used to wait for a Promise. **It can only be used inside an async function**.

```
async function doAwait() {
    let result = await Weather.findOne(options, function(err, weather) {

       if (err) {
            res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
           return res.status(200).send('Error occurs: ' + err);
       }

       if (weather) {
           res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
           return res.status(200).send(key + ' already exist.');
       }

       return weather;
   });

   console.log(result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have v7.10.0 and await/async are definitely supported in that version. I think it was added in 7.4, not sure though.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ node --version
v7.10.0
```

When I run:

```
const getDate = async () => {
    return new Date()
}
const printDate = async () => {
    const date = await getDate()
    return date
}
printDate().then(console.log).catch(console.error)
```

I get:

```
2017-07-04T09:04:27.311Z
```

Edit:
Just fyi, async/await didn't actually make it into ES7. It will most likely make it into this years edition of ECMAScript, though. https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/finished-proposals.md

Comment: thanks but I don't understand - where are `console.log` & `console.error` coming from?

Comment: They are built into nodejs and pretty much any browser.

Comment: *"It will most likely make it into this years edition of ECMAScript"* This year's revision was already released and yes, it did make it in ;)

Comment: Oh, I must have missed that. On Wikipedia it still says [not finished yet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#8th_Edition_.28not_yet_finished.29). When was it published?